# Overwrite Language and Currency Service

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to change where Spartacus saves the language and currency from sessionStorage to localStorage. The problem is both effects files (languages.effect.ts and currencies.effect.ts) are using sessionStorage. The services aren't provided in root and the effects are using the sessionStorage directly (this could be done in the service so we could change the implementation). Also on another note, I think the place where the initialize method is called is not the best (context-service-provider.ts).

[image]

I've tried adding a custom context (https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/automatic-context-configuration/) and also provided custom language and currency services but no luck switching those both services for a custom implementation.

Comment: Seems like we didn't thought about it. Could you create an github issue with request to make context extendable in terms of the storage and effects?

Comment: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/11345